# Como organizar títulos

Tags: html

Como organizar títulos em um documento html? Ex: eu tenho 2 ***section***, 3 ***div's***, um ***nav***, 1 aside e 3 ***article***. Então devo fazer a ordem de títulos e subtitulos em relação à cada elemento ou em relação à página toda? Ou seja cada elemento ou secção vai ter um h1 ou minha orientação deve ser em relação à página geral?

```
<h1>PRINCIPAL</h1>
<h2>ASSUNTO 1</h2>
<h3>SUBTITULO DO H2</h3>
<h2>ASSUNTO 2</h2>
<h3>SUBTITULO DO H2</h3>
<h2>ASSUNTO 3</h2>
<h3>SUBTITULO DO H2</h3>
</section>
<section class="lado esquerdo"> <nav></nav> <aside>outros elementos e assuntos <article>outros elementos e assuntos </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Poderia por favor colocar o conteúdo do seu HTML aqui?

Comment: em geral o foco é o conteúdo...

Comment: <section class="tudo">
 <section class="lado direito">
   <h1>PRINCIPAL</h1>
  <H2>ASSUNTO 1</H2>
  <H3>SUBTITULO DO H2</H3>
  <H2>ASSUNTO 2</H2>
  <H3>SUBTITULO DO H2</H3>
  <H2>ASSUNTO 3</H2>
  <H3>SUBTITULO DO H2</H3>
 </section>
 <section class="lado esquerdo">
  <nav></nav>
  <aside>outros elementos e assuntos
  <article>outros elementos e assuntos
  
 </section>
</section>                                                                                                                               seria algo assim.

Comment: Até aonde eu sei, só pode ter 1 elemento H1 por página. http://www.maujor.com/w3ctuto/qatips/useh1.html

Comment: Valeu, era isso que eu queria saber. Ajudou muito.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow em Português! Bem vindo ao [pt.so]. Sua pergunta está muito ampla, o padrão da comunidade são perguntas objetivas e que possuam ao menos uma resposta correta, como pode ser visto na [help] no link [ask]. Não entendi muito bem o que você se refere com "organizar títulos", poderia explicar melhor?. E aproveitando, faça um passeio pelo [tour] e depois você pode [edit] sua pergunta para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Answer (score 3):

> Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, mas vou tentar responder o que entendi.

A ordem dos cabeçalhos [h1, h2, h3,...](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/h1,_h2,_h3,_h4,_h5,_and_h6) "não interfere" na página. Isso vai de acordo de seu layout e como preferir. 
Veja esse exemplo com vários `<h1>` na página:

```html
<h1>PRINCIPAL</h1>
<h2>ASSUNTO 1</h2>
<h3>SUBTITULO DO H2</h3>
<h1>PRINCIPAL 2</h1>
<h2>ASSUNTO 2</h2>
<h3>SUBTITULO DO H2</h3>
<h1>PRINCIPAL 2</h1>
<h2>ASSUNTO 3</h2>
<h3>SUBTITULO DO H2</h3>
</section>
<section class="lado esquerdo"> <nav></nav> <aside>outros elementos e assuntos <article>outros elementos e assuntos </section>
</section>
```

Agora, note que se sua preocupação for [SEO](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otimiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_para_motores_de_busca), a abordagem muda. Para isso, vários fatores são levados em conta, inclusive o `<h1>`. Para isso, deve-se levar em conta alguns fatores, como:

> 1 – H1 com a palavra-chave da ideia principal
>
> 2 – H2 com as palavras-chave dos elementos da ideia principal
>
> 3 – H3 para dividir os elementos ainda mais e facilitado o entendimento e visualização das pessoas e dos robôs.

Note um exemplo prático da utilização das mesmas:

> Suponha que você deseja fazer um site de vendas de carros chamado de carros.com.
>
> `<h1>`
>
> ## A maior lista de carros novos, semi-novos e usados da internet
>
> Observe no exemplo de H1 acima que foram utilizados algumas possíveis keywords do site e o texto está escrito de forma que o usuário consiga entender.
>
> `<h2>`
>
> ### Venda de Carros da Marca FIAT
>
> Já no texto do H2 temos algo mais especifico, ou seja é uma subseção do H1, e novamente colocamos algumas keywords do site no H2, isso ajuda e muito os motores de busca e o usuário a acharem o que eles precisam no site
>
> `<h3>`
>
> #### Venda de Carros Fiat Punto
>
> Assim como no H2, o H3 tem que ser um complemento do H# superior. E essa regra deve ser seguida até a tag H6.

**Nota:** Você encontrará mais sobre o assunto se utilizar a palavra chave [Heading Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) ou Heading Tags.

Fontes:

- [SeoMarketing](http://www.seomarketing.com.br/heading-tags-h1-h2-h3-seo.php)
- [Developer.Mozzila](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements)
- [AgenciaMestre](http://www.agenciamestre.com/marketing-digital/tags-heading-seo/)
- [Conversion](http://www.conversion.com.br/blog/usando-tag-heading-h1-h2-h3-h4-em-seo/)

Answer (score 0):

Segue o que diz o W3C.

Fonte W3C => http://www.maujor.com/w3ctuto/qatips/useh1.html

> Use h1 para cabeçalhos de primeiro nível
>
> H1 é o elemento HTML usado para cabeçalhos de primeiro nível em uma
>   página:
>
> Se o documento for único em seu assunto, por exemplo: Coisas para se
>   ver e para se fazer em Genebra, o cabeçalho de primeiro nível
>   provavelmente será igual ao título do documento. Se o documento for um
>   de uma coletânea sobre um assunto, por exemplo: uma página sobre cães
>   fazendo parte de uma coletânea de páginas sobre animais de estimação,
>   o cabeçalho de primeiro nível pode ser um texto específico referente
>   ao assunto; apenas
>
> ## Cães
>
> enquanto o título pode ser qualquer
>   texto genérico referente ao assunto: Cães - Guia para animais de
>   estimação. Ao contrário do título, este elemento, os , podem
>   conter links, enfâse ou outro HTML phrase elements (elemento HTML para
>   frases).
>
> O tamanho de fonte padrão ("default") adotado por alguns browsers para
>   , infelizmente tem levado alguns projetistas a adotar o . Para
>   ferramentas que se utilizam da estrutura da página para seu
>   desempenho, como por exemplo Amaya's table of contents view
>   (NT:ferramenta Amaya que relaciona os conteúdos de uma página) esta
>   prática (usar  no lugar de ) é prejudicial. Considere o uso
>   das Folhas de estilos em cascata , que foram desenvolvidas para
>   expressar os tamanhos de fontes preferidos pelos projetistas para
>   elementos como os H1 e H2.

Comment: Você não está confundindo `<h1>` com `<title>` não?

Comment: Reclama com o W3C @Randrade

Comment: Não estou falando isso. Só estou dizendo que `H1` é para cabeçalhos, como o próprio texto diz. Agora 1 por página?

Comment: Melhorô? @Randrade

Comment: Agora ficou melhor. A própria página da [w3](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/h1,_h2,_h3,_h4,_h5,_and_h6) possui um exemplo com 2 `<h1>`. O elento `<title>` se encaixa em 1 por página.

Comment: @Randrade Entendi, obrigado.